# In Tensorflow, is it possible to append some summaries to already-merged summary_op?

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say, some built-in function returns `train_op` and `summary_op` where `summary_op` is defined by `tf.summary.merge(summaries, name='summary_op')`, and I cannot touch the function.

Also, let's say, I am going to use the built-in `slim.learning.train` which takes `train_op` and `summary_op` as input arguments.

```
# -- typical
train_op, summary_op = model_fn(image)
slim.learning.train(train_op, summary_op=summary_op)

# -- my question
train_op, summary_op = model_fn(image)
some_other_summary_list = some_another_function()
summary_op_ = ...  # is it possible to append some_other_summary_list to summary_op?
slim.learning.train(train_op, summary_op=summary_op_)
```

**How I can combine summaries in already-merged `summary_op` and newly-collected summaries `some_other_summary_list`?**

-- If I do `tf.merge_all(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES)` actually there will be too many summaries since, in `model_fn()` collect only useful and necessary summaries.

-- I can think of defining separate `summary_op2` and define `train_step_fn` as in:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.slim.python.slim.learning import train_step
def train_step_fn(...):
    ... = train_step(...)
    if iteration % 100 == 0: 
        summaries = session.run(summary_op2)
        summary_writer.add_summary(summaries, iteration)
slim.learning.train(train_op, summary_op=summary_op, train_step_fn=train_step_fn)
```

However, this seems too much if I can simply somehow append new summaries to `summary_op`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both "`summary_op` and newly-collected `summaries some_other_summary_list`" are created by `tf.summary.merge`, you can simply merge them again by `tf.summary.merge([summary_op, summaries some_other_summary_list])`, as demonstrated by this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.summary.scalar('a', tf.constant(0))
b = tf.summary.scalar('b', tf.constant(1))
c = tf.summary.scalar('c', tf.constant(2))
d = tf.summary.scalar('d', tf.constant(3))

ab = tf.summary.merge([a, b])
cd = tf.summary.merge([c, d])
abcd = tf.summary.merge([ab, cd])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.', sess.graph)
    summary = sess.run(abcd)
    writer.add_summary(summary)
```